# Eclipse not downloading the apache jars from pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I am using Eclipse as my IDE and want to build a maven program, but I see that neither my maven clean or maven install is working

```
For maven clean,I get the error:- "Failed to parse plugin descriptor for     
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 "
```

I also tried the help mentioned in the link

```
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please   
read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1]
```

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginDescriptorParsingException

but it is not helping

Also my maven install is not working,it shows the following error:

] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5

I had tried all the approaches mentioned in similar issues which include deleting the directories u nder .m2 folder, deleting .m2 folder, re-installing apache-maven on my system but nothing is working.

And when I run the same maven program under intelliJ, I could see the jar names but when I click on them it shows no contents which means they are not getting downloaded properly...'

So not able to work on my java maven project.Please help.

what is the fix for such environmental issues.

Even I tried re-installing eclipse, intelli J but nothing helps.

Comment: First check the build on command and before you start delete your local repository. I assume you have some network/proxy issues.

Comment: @khmarbaise : this is the error which I see when I give mvn clean command on the command prompt


INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central
 (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to PROXY:3120 [PROXY/192.168.108.68] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]

Comment: @khmarbaise even without any dependency in my pom.xml, I get the following error: https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins\:maven-clean-plugin\:pom\:2.5 from/to central (https\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)\: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org\:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.44.215] failed\: Connection timed out\: connect

Comment: and earlier the maven projects in eclipse were working without me configuring the proxies.Don't know what to do next? and how all of a sudden this issue is happening

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved by following the steps mentioned at:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-299

Answer (score -1):

try to download appropriate  maven version  from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi. and follow installaion steps mentioned.

set the "M2_HOME" and "MAVEN_HOME" as environment variables pointing to maven installation directory.restart your machine.

set the maven settings in eclipse through preferences tab.

Comment: The problem was to get a dependency and not Maven itself.